# I need help doing a basic geometry problem

Tags: geometry, polygons

I think it can be solved using parallels but I have no idea how.
[image]

Solve for "X"

Comment: The angles in the shape should add up to 720. Note the angle with B on the outside should be 360-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @user130512's comment, set up:

$$
90+90+2x+x+B+(360-B)=720
$$

Comment: Thank you, I realized I wasn't adding the (360 - B) into the process

Comment: you're welcome.